# Implementing BLE custom service to transfer files from watch to smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, iot, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create a ble custom service so that I  can send and receive some small files(~220 bytes) from my smartwatch(  bluetooth 4.0) to ios phone  using Bluetooth low energy.

Can I get any reference on how to create custom service (as standard services are not used for this) to transfer file?

I am expecting that once connection is established, both peripheral and central are able to receive and send data. Is it right?

Here I want to make watch as central and smartphone as peripheral is it possible?(I cant make watch as peripheral because it will be always connected to some other peripherals as a central, so it cannot be a central and peripheral at the same time )

And the final question is  that  my assumption to make smartphone as a peripheral and watch as central  is correct or not?
(  1.)more data has to be sent from watch to phone.
2.) watch will be already connected other ble devices as a central.)

I am using bluetopia 4.0 stack in watch.

Comment: Normally the watch would be the peripheral and the phone would be the central. It doesn't matter which is which in terms of data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a custom service. See the documentation on 'Performing Common Peripheral Role Tasks' [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1)

Yes, both Peripheral and Central can send and receive data. It depends on the properties and permissions of the characteristics in the GATT service.

The decision to make a device as Central or Peripheral depends on the use case and a variety of parameters like data rate, power consumption  etc.

Comment: Thank you I am able to communicate in both ways now, But The problem i cant write successively .GATT_Write_Request() is giving error code -1000 when I called it for second time.Can anyone Help me regarding this.

Comment: Are you calling the second GATT_Write_Request() back to back or in the callback when a response is received from the remote device? You may want to post a code snippet to get more help